# Spawn random objects without overlapping (Java)?

Tags: java, object, overlap

I'm developing a game in Java, and part of it requires that objects spawn at the top of the screen and proceed to fall down. I have three objects that can possibly spawn, and three possible `x` coordinates for them to spawn at, all stored in an array called `xCoordinate[]`.
One of the objects is of a class called `Enemy`, which inherits a class I have called `FallingThings`. In the FallingThings class, I have methods to generate new objects, my enemy method is below:

```
public static void generateNewEnemy() {
    xIndexEnemyOld = xIndexEnemy;
    xIndexEnemy = new Random().nextInt(3);
    if (delayTimer == 0) {
        while (xIndexEnemy == xIndexEnemyOld) {
            xIndexEnemy = new Random().nextInt(3);
        }
    }
    if (xIndexEnemy != xIndexMoney && xIndexEnemy != xIndexFriend) {
        Enemy enemy = new Enemy(xCoordinates[xIndexEnemy]);
        enemies.add((Enemy) enemy);
    } else {
        generateNewEnemy();
    }
}
```

`xIndexEnemy` represents the index of the xCoordinates array.
`xIndexMoney` and `xIndexFriend` are the indexes of the `xCoordinates` array for the two other objects (the comparisons with these values ensures that one object does not spawn directly on top of another).
The `delayTimer` variable represents the random delay between when new objects spawn, which was set earlier in my main class.
I store each instance of an `Enemy` object in an `ArrayList`.

Everything works except for the fact that sometimes, an object will spawn over itself (for example, the delay is 0, so two enemy objects spawn directly on top of each other, and proceed to fall down at the same speed at the same time).

I've been trying to crack this for the past two days, but I understand exactly why my code right now isn't working properly. I even tried implementing collision detection to check if another object already exists in the space, but that didn't work either.

I would be extremely grateful for any suggestions and ideas.

Comment: What is delayTimer? Where do you change it? When do you call generate new enemy?

Comment: Use just a single instance of Random for a better distribución.

Comment: @OrestSavchak delayTimer is the variable I use for a timer I created in my main class that dictates when new objects spawn (between 0 and 2 seconds). I assign it a value in my main class and from there call a method that randomly determines whether to generate an enemy, friend, or money, and if it returns enemy, generateNewEnemy() is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT2**

It seems that you still don't understand the problem with your function. It was addressed in the other answer but I'll try to make it more clear.

```
public static void generateNewEnemy() {
    xIndexEnemyOld = xIndexEnemy;
```

This is just wrong. You can't set the Old index without having actually used a new index yet.

```
    xIndexEnemy = new Random().nextInt(3);
    if (delayTimer == 0) {
        while (xIndexEnemy == xIndexEnemyOld) {
            xIndexEnemy = new Random().nextInt(3);
        }
    }
```

This is actually ok. You're generating an index until you get one that is different. It may not be the most elegant of solutions but it does the job.

```
    if (xIndexEnemy != xIndexMoney && xIndexEnemy != xIndexFriend) {
        Enemy enemy = new Enemy(xCoordinates[xIndexEnemy]);
        enemies.add((Enemy) enemy);
    } else {
        generateNewEnemy();
    }
}
```

This is your problem (along with setting the Old index back there). Not only do you have to generate an index thats different from the Old index, it must also be different from IndexMoney and IndexFriend.

Now, what happens if, for example, IndexOld = 0, IndexMoney = 1 and IndexFriend = 2? You have to generate an index that's different from 0, so you get (again, for instance) 1. IndexMoney is 1 too, so the condition will fail and you do a recursive call. (Why do you even have a recursive call?)

OldIndex was 0, and now in the next call you're setting it to 1. So IndexOld = 1, IndexMoney = 1 and IndexFriend = 2. Do you see the problem now? The overlapped index is now wrong. And the new index can only be 0 no matter how many recursive calls it takes.

You're shooting yourself in the foot more than once. The recursive call does not result in an infinite loop (stack overflow actually) because you're changing the Old index. (Which, again is in the wrong place)

That if condition is making it so the newly generated index cannot overlap ANY of the previous indexes. From what you said before it's not what you want.

You can simplify your function like this,

```
public static void generateNewEnemy() {
    xIndexEnemy = new Random().nextInt(3);
    if (delayTimer == 0) {
        while (xIndexEnemy == xIndexEnemyOld) {
            xIndexEnemy = new Random().nextInt(3);
        }
    }

    Enemy enemy = new Enemy(xCoordinates[xIndexEnemy]);
    enemies.add((Enemy) enemy);
    xIndexEnemyOld = xIndexEnemy;
    // Now that you used the new index you can store it as the Old one
}
```

Will it work? It will certainly avoid overlapping when the delayTimer is 0 but I don't know the rest of your code (nor do I want to) and what do you do. It's you who should know.

About my suggestions, they were alternatives for how to generate the index you wanted. I was assuming you would know how to fit them in your code, but you're still free to try them after you've fixed the actual problem.

---

**Original Answer**

Here's one suggestion.

One thing you could do is to have these enemies "borrow" elements from the array. Say you have an array,

```
ArrayList< Float > coordinates = new ArrayList< Float >();
// Add the coordinates you want ...
```

You can select one of the indexes as you're doing, but use the maximum size of the array instead and then remove the element that you choose. By doing that you are removing one of the index options.

```
int nextIndex = new Random().nextInt( coordinates.size() );
float xCoordinate = coordinates.get( nextIndex );
coordinates.remove( nextIndex ); // Remove the coordinate
```

Later, when you're done with the value (say, when enough time has passed, or the enemy dies) you can put it back into the array.

```
coordinates.add( xCoordinate );
```

Now the value is available again and you don't have to bother with checking indexes.

Well, this is the general idea for my suggestion. You will have to adapt it to make it work the way you need, specifically when you place the value back into the array as I don't know where in your code you can do that.

---

**EDIT:**

Another alternative is, you keep the array that you previously had. No need to remove values from it or anything.

When you want to get a new coordinate create an extra array with only the values that are available, that is the values that won't overlap other objects.

```
...
if (delayTimer == 0) {
    ArrayList< Integer > availableIndexes = new ArrayList< Integer >();
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i ) {
        if ( i != xIndexEnemyOld ) {
            availableIndexes.add( i );
        }
    }
    int selectedIndex = new Random().nextInt( availableIndexes.size() );
    xIndexEnemy = availableIndexes.get( selectedIndex );
}
// Else no need to use the array
else {
    xIndexEnemy = new Random().nextInt( 3 );
}
...
```

And now you're sure that the index you're getting should be different, so no need to check if it overlaps.
The downside is that you have to create this extra array, but it makes your conditions simpler.

(I'm keeping the "new Random()" from your code but other answers/comments refer that you should use a single instance, remember that)

Comment: You're placing the x coordinate right back into the array so it's no different from what you were previously doing. You should put the coordinate back only when it's available, perhaps when the enemy has fallen low enough or has been killed. I don't know the actual condition that should make the coordinate available again.

Comment: Sorry for deleting my comment, the formatting looked bad. If the coordinate is no longer available then my other objects like Friend and Money won't be able to show up on screen. I need all the coordinates to always be available for everyone, but need to implement a method to prevent overlapping when the delayTimer == 0.

Comment: Then you could remove the coordinate from the array during the time in which you don't want any overlaps. And when that time has passed you can place it back in the array?

Comment: @AmanDureja Ok, I've edited, it's more like what you previously had.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help! I tried implementing your first suggestion, but that still resulted in some overlapping. Now when I implement your second idea, I get an error at: int selectedIndex = new Random().nextInt(availableIndexes.size()), saying that the bound must be positive. This leads me to believe that the availableIndexes array is not being populated, but I implemented it exactly as you wrote. Any ideas?

Comment: @AmanDureja https://ideone.com/Q8gVn2 It compiles correctly in this short example and correctly sets the index to either 0 or 2, while confirming that the array has size 2. Are you sure you copied everything?

Comment: Thank you for the link! Unfortunately even after confirming that my code matches yours I am still getting an IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive, when I define the int selectedIndex. Here is my generateNewEnemy() class (it won't compile on this link because it's missing all the other files, but you know what it's supposed to do): http://goo.gl/iAJm1t

Comment: Ah, of course. The way you wrote it, in the case that the delay timer is not zero the array goes uninitialized.  If the timer is not zero then you have to add all of the 3 indexes since none will overlap. But I believe that if the delay timer is not zero then you don't need to use the array at all. I'll edit my code again.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help! I truly appreciate you taking the time to explain where I went wrong and how and why to correct it. I used your simplified function and it's working quite well now! I finally understand the problems and how to implement your suggestions into the rest of my code. Thanks again, you're awesome! =)

Answer (score 0):

As I see, if delay == 0 all is good, but if not, you have a chance to generate new enemy with the same index. Maybe you want to call `return;` if delayTimer != 0?

**UPDATED**

Look what you have in such case:
OldEnemyIndex = 1
NewEnemyIndex = random(3) -> 1
DelayTimer = 2

Then you do not pass to your if statement, then in the next if all is ok, if your enemy has no the same index with money or something else, so you create new enemy with the same index as previous

Comment: What I want to do is if delayTimer == 0, then keep changing the value of xIndexEnemy until it is different from that of xIndexEnemyOld (which should prevent it from spawning on top of the already existing enemy object), hence the while() loop. After that, I proceed as normal with creating the object.

Comment: And yes, better is using one Random instance. And why do you cast enemy variable to Enemy class? It is useless code .

Comment: Or if your timer is not zero, they can not spawn at the same time?

Comment: a new object generates after a set amount of time. If the timer is not zero, then there is no issue with overlapping since by the time the new object spawns at the top of the screen, the previous is already falling down. So if the timer is not zero, they cannot spawn at the same time. I should have been clearer in my original question.    Initially, if I didn't cast the enemy variable to the Enemy class, I was getting an error, but I changed it again and now it's all good, I don't know what was up with Eclipse before.